# How to inject a variable into a function's closure without using "with" or "this"?

Tags: javascript, closures

Suppose that I have defined a function like following:

```
const addX = (y) => x + y
```

It is obvious that the `x` inside the function body is a free variable.

If I want to specify a value to `x` after the definition of `addX`, and keep the principle about not using `this` and `with`, is there any possible way?

This is very useful when we are designing an EDSL in JavaScript.

NOTE: I know that we can do some similar thing like following:

```
const add = (x) => (y) => x + y
const addX = add(1)
```

But In my case, the definition of `addX` is already done, so that is not working.

Comment: Just change the value of `x` in the enclosing lexical context.

Comment: Where is `x` declared? Is it a global variable?

Comment: "*the definition of addX is already done*" - please be more specific about your use case. Who defined `addX` and in what context? Was the script preprocessed by anything (or could you add a stage to do that)?

Comment: @Bergi understand my use case need to read about [this package](https://github.com/luochen1990/ast-reducer), in this package, I use 'this' to inject something to the rule definition, which is represented by a lambda expression, it works well in CoffeeScript, but not works in ES6's lambda expression, in which the 'this' is always binded.

Comment: @luochen1990 I don't see any problem to just pass a second parameter next to `def` (or even require `function(def) { def(…)(… => this(…)) }` in there)

Comment: Actually, it is not possible to pass it as a second parameter next to `def`, just suppose that we name it `rec`, the value of `rec` can not be decided until we really call the function named `Reducer.runState()`, an alternative way is to pass `rec` as a reference, and assign a new value to it everytime we call `Reducer.runState()`, but that is very ugly, since we have to simulate a reference via wrapping it into an object or array in JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a value to the global variable and call the function then.

```js
var addX = y => x + y,   // global scope
    x,                   // global scope
    add = xx => y => {   // get all values
       x = xx;           // assign to global x
       return addX(y);   // call fn with y and take global x
    };

console.log(add(10)(32));
```